# Using JCE Ciphers as a Digest?

Tags: cryptography, hash, java

[Some of the BouncyCastle methods](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/agreement/srp/SRP6VerifierGenerator.html#init%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger,%20org.bouncycastle.crypto.Digest%29) take a `Digest` as input. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Hash_functions_based_on_block_ciphers and http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/ it should be possible to use a block cipher as a hash function.

So does that mean that it should be possible to use any of the JCE ciphers (such as Blowfish) as a Digest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot *use* a block cipher as a hash function; you can, if you are a cryptographer, *design* a hash function out of a block cipher, which means that the block cipher will be an important element within the hash function -- important, but not alone. You need more.

(Analogy: a car can be powered by an engine -- and often is. However, there is more to a car than an engine, and there are a lot of ways to build a car around an engine. Many such ways are bad, too, and won't result in a safe, efficient or beautiful car.)